# Image Resize From Excel to PPt

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have got the below code to copy the image from range of cells of excel to PPT, but the image pasted on the PPT does is of different dimensions.
Can someone tell me how can I fix size of the image when pasted in PPT.
I am pasting my code below for your reference.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object

'Unhiding the sheets
  Worksheets("Sheet4").Visible = xlSheetVisible

'Copy Range from Excel
  Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C12")

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next

    'Is PowerPoint already opened?
      Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

    'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
      If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
        Exit Sub
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Create a New Presentation
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

'Mupltiple Slides
    'List of PPT Slides to Paste to
    MySlideArray = Array(1, 2, 3)

    'List of Excel Ranges to Copy from
    MyRangeArray = Array(Sheet2.Range("A1:AB71"), Sheet1.Range("A1:AL70"), Sheet5.Range("A1:AE56"))

    'Loop through Array data
    For x = LBound(MySlideArray) To UBound(MySlideArray)

'Add a slide to the Presentation
  Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 12) '12 = ppLayoutBlank 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppslidelayout

'Copy Excel Range
  'rng.Copy
  MyRangeArray(x).Copy
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
  Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.count)

    'Set position:
      myShape.Left = 0
      myShape.Top = 0


  Next x
  'Message Box
   MsgBox ("Please is ready !!")


'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
  PowerPointApp.Visible = True
  PowerPointApp.Activate

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Hiding the sheets back
  Worksheets("Sheet4").Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to run your code as posted. I get an "Object required" error on the line that tries to fill MyRangeArray with the 3 ranges.

Comment: it doesnt give me an error. Could be because you don't have the image I am trying to paste in the PPT.

Comment: Could you tell me how to write the code for resizing the image while pasting it in the ppt

Comment: Add myShape.Width and myShape.Height after myShape.Top = 0 and set them to your preferred values.